# JQuery - get .html() after having set with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm using jQuery with the power of localStorage.

Here is what I have:

```
<textarea name="localStorageString" id="localStorageString"></textarea>
<script>
  var userJson = localStorage.getItem('userJson');
  $('#localStorageString').html(userJson);
  $('#localStorageString').keyup(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

The `textarea` is correctly filled, the problem is when I modify it, it always alerts the same value (set by `html(userJson)`).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I forgot this one. Why `.html()` doesn't work ?

`html()` - it's the native JavaScript `.innerHTML` function. It takes everything (all the nodes) inside the tag as a string.

```
<div id="Node">
   <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
console.info($('#Node').html()); // <a href="#">Hello</a>
```

`val()` - that's `form.element.value`.

Comment: Ok. But in the case of a textarea, why wouldn't be the same result ?

Comment: Its jQuery API. I guess it provides you unified access to the form elements and their values. It really makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You need `$(this).val()` to get the value of a form element.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `html()`, use `val()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: don't use `.html()` on a `<textarea>` (or other form elements). Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) (or `.value`).

```
$('#localStorageString').val(userJson)
.keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Zz2cF/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.val()` instead of `.html()`.

`.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val

`.html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html